# Converting HTML text to Word Doc without saving at Local

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have a requirement for saving a word DOC with HTML content in it. I have the html content in a string variable. Due to security reasons I am not authorized to save the file in local. I have to pass the doc as a byte stream into another server. Is it possible to perform this.
only solutions I have seen are saving the document in local and converting it to a byte stream.

Comment: You can utilize `NetworkStream` class to read the HTML content from your string variable and send that stream object to the other server.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option for you, you could consider using a Document Conversion SDK that can perform the conversion without saving anything locally. For example, I am familiar with the LEADTOOLS Document Converter class (Since I work for the vendor) which is able to convert from a HTML stream to DOC stream.

The code for this would look something like the following:

```
MemoryStream outputDocStream = new MemoryStream();

// Example of the HTML Byte Array input
string HTMLString = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" > <head> <title>Test HTML</title> <style type=\"text/css\"> .style1 { font-size: xx-large; } </style> </head> <body> <p> Hello <span class=\"style1\">World!</span></p> </body> </html>";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLString);

// Extract string and write to memory stream
MemoryStream inputHTMLStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLString));

// Convert to Doc and place the output in DOC Word in the output memory stream
var options = new LoadDocumentOptions();
using (var document = DocumentFactory.LoadFromStream(inputHTMLStream, options))
{
   using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
   {
      var jobData = new DocumentConverterJobData();
      jobData.Document = document;
      jobData.DocumentFormat = DocumentFormat.Doc;
      jobData.OutputDocumentStream = outputDocStream;
      jobData.JobName = "conversion job";
      var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
      documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
   }
}
```

The output memory stream will contain the produced DOC content.